# How to adjust the scaling of a colorbar legend in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I am making plots of national data regarding methane emissions; the problem is the magnitude of my data varies from E8 to E13, so many orders of magnitude. My scale on the legend comes out skewed to the larger extreme, as I'll attach an image to show:

[An example map with the legend showing varying color only within the E12 magnitude, so all data looks identical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRcTD.png)

here's the code I've been using, I was hoping the limits = c( , ) would work, but it doesn't adjust scale.

```
register_google(key = api)
Map <- get_map(location=c(lon=-98, lat=32), source="google", maptype="satellite", zoom=4)
Map_Plot <-ggmap(Map, extent = "panel", xlab = "Latitude", ylab = "Longitude")
Map_Plot + geom_point(data = AC_Data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = Emissions), 
size = 2, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette, name = "Emissions", limits = c(1E3, 9.99E12)) +
  labs(y = "Latitude", x = "Longitude", title = "AC Emissions") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2))) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.5))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(1))) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(1, "cm")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(1))) +   
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(1.3, .5))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work better on a log scale? E.g. `scale_colour_gradient(trans = "log10", ...)`

Comment: @teunbrand Yes actually, R couldn't handle the exponential scale, taking the log fixed the issue